# Restrict Google bot's access based on URL parameters

Tags: php, joomla, search-engine, robots.txt, googlebot

For example I have the following link:

```
http://broodds.com/index.php/en/component/bet/?view=oddsdetails&bet_id=4e9dc53b96df3&odds=q1
```

I don't want to give access to the Google bot if the `view` is `oddsdetails`, is it possible to disable that. I'm using Joomla framework, so already there is a robots.txt, I want to extend that if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template within the index.php `<head></head>` of your template you could use this:

```
$view = JRequest::getString('view');
if ($view == 'oddsdetail') { echo '<meta name="robots" content="NONE" />'; }
```

additionally, if you want to allow the robot to continue looking beyond this page, then what's best is to use:

```
$view = JRequest::getString('view');
if ($view == 'oddsdetail') { echo '<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX" />'; }
```

This means Google won't index this page, but it will continue to go to any subsidiary links. NONE just tells Google to completely ignore this page.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Based on your answer, added the following to the view 
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData('robots', "NONE");

Comment: ah yeah, sorry to skip out using the framework for the meta add, I figured you'd be able to work with it based off the view if statement and location :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using parameter handling in google webmaster tools which is for these types of urls.